# TOR VPN only allows usage for Google and gives an error for other applications

Tags: orbot, vpn, torcheck

I have used a TOR VPN provided by The TOR Project (Orbot for Android) I have run a check on Ooni probe with the TOR VPN active and the TOR test failed. All other tests passed however, so this is not a problem using TOR with applocations just some error caused by applocations using TOR. For example when I search on spotify it simply says "Something went wrong. Try agian?" If a song changes the download file will become corrupt. This only happens for some TOR circuits. It seems like this happens more and more often since I started using a TOR VPN in 2021. Only websites accessed by Google will load. Here is the Ooni probe log; im stumped.

````
Looking up OONI backends... please, be patient
sessionresolver: https://mozilla.cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query... ok
session: using probe services: {Address:https://api.ooni.io Type:https Front:}
contacted bouncer
Looking up your location... please, be patient
iplookup: using stun_google
sessionresolver: https://dns.google/dns-query... ok
iplookup: using cloudflare
sessionresolver: https://dns.google/dns-query... ok
geoip lookup
resolver lookup
Opening report... please, be patient
open report
Starting measurement with index 0
TCPConnect 131.188.40.189:443... ok
TCPConnect 66.111.2.131:9001... ok
TLSHandshake 131.188.40.189:443 with sni=... connection_reset
tor: access 131.188.40.189:443/or_port_dirauth: connection_reset
TLSHandshake 66.111.2.131:9001 with sni=... connection_reset
tor: access 66.111.2.131:9001/or_port_dirauth: connection_reset
TCPConnect 38.229.1.78:80... ok
tor: access 199.58.81.140:80/dir_port: connection_reset
TCPConnect 38.229.33.83:80... ok
tor: access 38.229.1.78:80/obfs4: context deadline exceeded
tor: access 38.229.33.83:80/obfs4: context deadline exceeded
tor: access 45.66.33.45:80/dir_port: connection_reset
tor: access 193.23.244.244:80/dir_port: connection_reset
TCPConnect 51.222.13.177:80... ok
TCPConnect 193.23.244.244:443... ok
TLSHandshake 193.23.244.244:443 with sni=... connection_reset
tor: access 193.23.244.244:443/or_port_dirauth: connection_reset
TCPConnect 192.95.36.142:443... ok
tor: access 51.222.13.177:80/obfs4: success
TCPConnect 37.218.245.14:38224... ok
tor: access 192.95.36.142:443/obfs4: success
TCPConnect 193.11.166.194:27025... ok
tor: access 37.218.245.14:38224/obfs4: success
TCPConnect 209.148.46.65:443... ok
tor: access 193.11.166.194:27025/obfs4: success
TCPConnect [2a0c:4d80:42:702::1]:27015... host_unreachable
tor: access [2a0c:4d80:42:702::1]:27015/obfs4: host_unreachable
tor: access 171.25.193.9:443/dir_port: connection_reset
tor: access 154.35.175.225:80/dir_port: connection_reset
TCPConnect 199.58.81.140:443... ok
TLSHandshake 199.58.81.140:443 with sni=... connection_reset
tor: access 199.58.81.140:443/or_port_dirauth: connection_reset
TCPConnect 204.13.164.118:443... ok
TLSHandshake 204.13.164.118:443 with sni=... connection_reset
tor: access 204.13.164.118:443/or_port_dirauth: connection_reset
TCPConnect 146.57.248.225:22... ok
tor: access 209.148.46.65:443/obfs4: success
TCPConnect 128.31.0.39:9101... ok
TLSHandshake 128.31.0.39:9101 with sni=... connection_reset
tor: access 128.31.0.39:9101/or_port_dirauth: connection_reset
tor: access 86.59.21.38:80/dir_port: connection_reset
TCPConnect 193.11.166.194:27020... ok
tor: access 146.57.248.225:22/obfs4: success
TCPConnect 144.217.20.138:80... ok
tor: access 193.11.166.194:27020/obfs4: success
TCPConnect 86.59.21.38:443... ok
TLSHandshake 86.59.21.38:443 with sni=... connection_reset
tor: access 86.59.21.38:443/or_port_dirauth: connection_reset
TCPConnect 45.66.33.45:443... ok
TLSHandshake 45.66.33.45:443 with sni=... connection_reset
tor: access 45.66.33.45:443/or_port_dirauth: connection_reset
TCPConnect 85.31.186.98:443... ok
tor: access 85.31.186.98:443/obfs4: success
TCPConnect 193.11.166.194:27015... ok
tor: access 193.11.166.194:27015/obfs4: success
TCPConnect 85.31.186.26:443... ok
tor: access 85.31.186.26:443/obfs4: success
TCPConnect 45.145.95.6:27015... ok
tor: access 45.145.95.6:27015/obfs4: success
tor: access 128.31.0.39:9131/dir_port: connection_reset
tor: access 66.111.2.131:9030/dir_port: connection_reset
tor: access 131.188.40.189:80/dir_port: connection_reset
TCPConnect 171.25.193.9:80... ok
TLSHandshake 171.25.193.9:80 with sni=... connection_reset
tor: access 171.25.193.9:80/or_port_dirauth: connection_reset
TCPConnect 154.35.175.225:443... ok
TLSHandshake 154.35.175.225:443 with sni=... connection_reset
tor: access 154.35.175.225:443/or_port_dirauth: connection_reset
tor: access 204.13.164.118:80/dir_port: connection_reset
tor: access 144.217.20.138:80/obfs4: context deadline exceeded
Submitting measurement... please, be patient
sessionresolver: [{"URL":"https://cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query","Score":0.9999999999999901},{"URL":"https://dns.google/dns-query","Score":0.999990091},{"URL":"https://mozilla.cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query","Score":0.99990091},{"URL":"http3://dns.google/dns-query","Score":0.000999999999991},{"URL":"https://dns.quad9.net/dns-query","Score":0.0009999991000000001},{"URL":"http3://mozilla.cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query","Score":0.0009100000000000002},{"URL":"http3://cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query","Score":0.00010000000000000003},{"URL":"system:///","Score":0}]```
````

Comment: My guess is, that the ooni test fails for trying to connect tor from tor, which is nonsense. Regarding Spotify, maybe they are blocking tor, and some exit nodes aren't in their list and do work, but others aren't.

Answer (score 0):

looking at your logs there're censors on your line - the *connection_reset* clauses are facts of successful DPI intrusions/blocking. Or your bridges are dead, so no connection is possible to them, but it looks more likely as a DPI